# Get multiple Set-Cookie headers from NSHTTPURLResponse

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, foundation

I'm trying to access `Set-Cookie` headers sent in an http response:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    NSDictionary *headers = [httpResponse allHeaderFields];
    NSLog([headers description]);
}
```

The HTTP server sends two `Set-Cookie` headers like so:

```
Set-Cookie: foo=1; httponly; Path=/
Set-Cookie: bar=2; httponly; Path=/
```

However, the [`[HTTPResponse allHeaderFields]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nshttpurlresponse/1417930-allheaderfields?language=objc) interface is combining the multiple `Set-Cookie` headers into one comma-delimited string:

```
"Set-Cookie" = "foo=1; httponly; Path=/, bar=2; httponly; Path=/"
```

[This cocoa-dev mailing list message](https://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2007/Mar/msg00873.html) confirms my observation.

Is there an interface to get each `Set-Cookie` header separately or access the raw headers?

Comment: I think you have to do it manually: `NSArray *setCookiesHeaders = headers[@""Set-Cookie"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","]`, and parse it to retrieve you info. The thing, is that the value are string, and headers are dictionary, so you can only have one key of each, and apparently they combine them with a "," if it already exists.

Comment: Separating the string by commas is not enough as the cookie itself may contain commas as well.

Answer (score 1):

iOS and macOS define an `NSHTTPCookie` class which can parse and give you the information you're looking for:

```
NSArray<NSHTTPCookie *> *cookies = [NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields: [httpResponse allHeaderFields] forURL: [httpResponse url]];
```

For more info, see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nshttpcookie?language=objc) for `NSHTTPCookie`.

Comment: This will not give you all cookies, This only give you cookies if request domain matches with response cookies.